# Call to a member function bindParam() on a non object

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not sure how this is supposed to work, any input would be beneficial.

```
function deleteRemindersFromTable(PDO $dbh, $timeStamp)
{
    $formattedDate = date('y-m-j', $timeStamp);

    try {

        $sth = $dbh->query("UPDATE reminders SET sent=true WHERE date=(:date)");
        $sth->bindParam(':date', $formattedDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `prepare` instead of `query`.

Comment: That moved the error but it is spitting out a blank array.

Comment: What else do you want an update query to return?

Comment: ha, good point. Thanks for your help JDO

Comment: @jdo The number of rows updated ;-)

Comment: @hjpotter92 You'll get it by calling `rowCount`, but that's also true for select, delete, ... And if there would be some return value, it is not stored in his `$sth` var.